# How to config proper view size with UIImageView and UIImage?

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, uiimageview

I'm new to iOS programming, now I'm writing a camera app using AVFoundation. My problem is I have to preview the image just taken at full screen size, but no matter how I tried, I just got a clipped image (top left proportion of the original image) displayed full screen size on the phone. My image just taken is at 1920 * 1080 res, my UIImageView is set to AspectFit, and on the storyboard, it appears at full screen size.

The code to display the image is like,

```
   [self.imageView setFrame:self.view.bounds];
   [self.imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit] ;
   [self.imageView setImage:image] ;
   [self.view insertSubview:_imageView aboveSubview:_previewView] ;
   [self.view bringSubviewToFront:_stillButton] ;
   [self.view bringSubviewToFront:_maskButton] ;
   [self.view bringSubviewToFront:_confirmButton] ;
```

And when I observe the size of the UIImageView object self.imageView, the size is not at the screen size, but just 320*568. However, the previewView which is a AVFoundation camera shooting preview object, it is also at 320*568, but it appears the previewView size is correct from the looking of the running app. and at last, the self.view.frame.size is also 320*568.

So my problem is how to view the image taken at 1920*1080 at full screen size?

Answer (score 0):

try this: 
`imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter`